# NodeJS: Why is my POST request not working?

Tags: node.js, http, post, header

I'm trying to use the net module in nodejs to send a POST request while connecting to a socket.

I've tried sending a GET request which indeed does work, but I can't seem to get the POST request to work.

This is the code:

```
socket.write(`POST /page.php HTTP/1.1\r\n
                      Host: domain.com\r\n
                      Connection: close\r\n
                      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3\r\n
                      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (MeeGo; NokiaN9) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) NokiaBrowser/8.5.0 Mobile Safari/534.13\r\n
                      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n
                      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
                      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n
                      Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n
                      Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
                      Content-Length: 0\r\n\r\n`);
```

I've "debugged" it, and I've noticed some 301 Moved Permanently and Temporarily redirected responses from the host.

Comment: Well, Post (as opposed to Get) doesn't have a redirect method, hence the error you are getting. Make sure the resource posted to returns a 2xx-class status code.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Well, I'm trying to send an empty post request. How exactly do I get it to work?

Comment: You don't, at least not with that resource. Take note of where the 301 leads and post to that resource.

Comment: @LucaKiebel apparently I'm getting 503 unknown method and 400 Bad Request now. I have no clue what's going on.

Comment: Try it with a server you have control over. Websites can block post requests

Comment: @LucaKiebel i'm testing it on my website. That is where I get the errors. Is the POST request above ok though?

Comment: Your website or your server, there's a big difference in how much control you have. Take a look at the documentation of your server-software to find out how to unblock methods.

Comment: @LucaKiebel i've tested my website on different API testing websites which allow you to send requests using any method you want, and on their website, everything works fine.